# how to get sub directories in int-ftp:outbound-gateway with expression?

Tags: spring, ftp, spring-integration

firstly thanks for attention
i have spring integration project that listen ftp server to receive files in different directory and process it,ftp directory structure is:
ftp-root
-----------a\
-----------------in\
---------------------------a.txt
-----------------out\
------------b\
-----------------in\
---------------------------b.txt
-----------------out\

i used `int-ftp:outbound-gateway` adapter to run ls recursive command,how to write `expression` attr in `int-ftp:outbound-gateway` that get *a.txt* and *b.txt* in **`in`** directories, my adapter code is:

```
 <int-ftp:outbound-gateway id="gateway1"
                              session-factory="ftpClientFactory"
                              request-channel="inbound1"
                              reply-channel="outbound"
                              reply-timeout="777"
                              auto-create-local-directory="false"
                              auto-startup="true"
                              command="ls"
                              command-options="-1 -R"
                              expression="'*/in/'"
                              mput-regex=".*">

    </int-ftp:outbound-gateway>
```

but not correctly worked, how to write it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `MGET` operation is for you:

```
<int-ftp:outbound-gateway id="gatewayLS"
    session-factory="ftpSessionFactory"
    request-channel="inbound"
    command="mget"
    command-options=""
    expression="payload"
    local-directory="/tmp/out"
    reply-channel="resultChannel"/>
```

[FTP Outbound Gateway MGET](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/ftp.html#ftp-outbound-gateway).

Comment: yes that's right,how to write `expression` attr that get only sub-directories , set `expression` to `/*/in/` but not correctly worked

Comment: It doesn't work. Please, read the docs I've pointed out. You really need `filter` to skip files, and therefore undesired dirs

Comment: ,the adapter has been changed but thrown the following exception
`org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: ; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to execute on session; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: path must not be null`  thanks for help me

Comment: Haven't you tried to use `*` as a path in request message ?

Comment: it's worked correctly @Artem   
`<int-ftp:outbound-gateway id="gateway1"
                              session-factory="ftpClientFactory"
                              request-channel="inbound1"
                              reply-channel="outbound"
                              reply-timeout="777"
                              command="mget"
                              command-options="-R"
                              expression="payload"
                              local-directory="."
            >

    </int-ftp:outbound-gateway>`